# Autohotkey right-side prefix out-of-bound effect, correct behavior?

Tags: autohotkey

I encounter a problem, illustrated as in this little snippet:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
^a:: MsgBox, Ctrl+A press in notepad
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
>^a:: MsgBox, Ctrl+A pressed in CMD window
#IfWinActive
```

I'd like to

- have <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (no matter left-or-right Ctrl) to trigger a msgbox on 
  Notepad;
- and have only Right <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to trigger msgbox on a CMD window.

But the actual behavior on Notepad is: **Only left Ctrl+A can trigger the msgbox, right Ctrl+A exhibits the original "Select All" behavior.** What's wrong? How can one `#IfWinActive` context's `>` prefix affects another `#IfWinActive` context?

Tried with Autohotkey 1.1.19.02 and 1.1.22.09 on Windows 7, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen that one... maybe a quirk.  Try explicit left/right definitions.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
>^a:: 
<^a:: 
    MsgBox, Ctrl+A press in notepad
return
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
>^a:: MsgBox, Ctrl+A pressed in CMD window
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Although this may be a workaround, I would refrain from doing this, because it would have *every* context aware *Ctrl+<n>* hotkey definition to double the work, which make the script very ugly.